# How to use rvt file in HTML page to preview 360 virtual tour?

Tags: html, 3d, revit-api, 360-virtual-reality

I have a file that is a 3d 1st person virtual tour of a city. I want to embed that file into html so that users who come into the page also navigate through city. I have no idea what file format is supported and what to use. How to use 360 vr tour revit file into browser page?

I tried using A360 to upload files and then embed that file into my html page but my rvt file is so big and I am not sure if A360 can render it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [A360 Viewer](https://viewer.autodesk.com/). You can simply upload the RVT BIM there just as it is. There is no limit to the file size.